# Not understood meaning of sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What does this sentence mean?⬇

"Your teachers coming to our schools would fulfil the contract."

Especially "Your teachers coming to our schools..."

I do not really know how to understand this.

Comment: Welcome to the ell, would you please add the source or a link to the source? You can add new contents by clicking on edit below the tags.

Comment: I think that's another one of those reduced relative clauses - "**that are**"

Answer (score 1):

The confusion is probably because this is an archaic construction. It is called genitive case. *Teachers* is not the subject of the sentence, although it appears to be because it comes first. The gerund phrase *coming to our schools* is the real subject, and it belongs to *the teachers* because it is an action they will undertake.

To be grammatically correct, the sentence should have a possessive apostrophe after *teachers*:
*Your teachers' coming to our schools would fulfill the contract.*

Other ways to phrase the same idea:

- Your teachers, by coming to our schools, would fulfill the contract.
- By coming to our schools, your teachers would fulfill the contract.
- To fulfill the contract, your teachers must come to our schools.
- Coming to our schools is how your teachers would fulfill the contract.
- The contract will be fulfilled when your teachers come to our schools.
- etc. etc.